# Why it is not opening defined folder via intent in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent

**This code is redirecting to drive with open navigation but not opening actual given path**

**OLD Code**

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/foldername/");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/csv");
startActivity(intent);
```

The path value I am getting through uri is:
**/storage/emulated/0/myfolder**

**NEW Code**

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
resultIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
Uri uri = 
Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + 
"/myfolder/");
resultIntent.setType("*/*");
resultIntent.putExtra("android.provider.extra.INITIAL_URI", uri);
// show the entire internal storage tree
//resultIntent.putExtra("android.content.extra.SHOW_ADVANCED", true);
startActivity(resultIntent);
```

Let me know the issue where is the problem in this code.

Comment: did you add permission in manifest? and ask for permission ??

Comment: Have a look at `Intent.EXTRA.INITIAL_URI`.

Comment: But better use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT for that to work on Android Q.

Comment: @KaranKhurana Yes, I have added permission in manifest and asking on runtime also, issue is with android 7 and above

Comment: First, `text/csv` is not the MIME type of a directory. A directory does not have a MIME type. Second, `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` does not take a `Uri` as input. See the "Input" section in [the documentation for `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_GET_CONTENT). You are welcome to try putting that `Uri` in [`EXTRA_INITIAL_URI`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/DocumentsContract.html#EXTRA_INITIAL_URI) instead, but there is no requirement for `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` to honor that or to understand a `file` `Uri` there.

Comment: @blackapps Even using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT it's not opening the desired folder. It's opening like this attached ss. https://ibb.co/nDXFDW9

Comment: Show complete code in your post please.

Comment: @SaumilVaghela https://stackoverflow.com/a/67553040/9846650

Answer (score -1):

```
private static final int READ_REQUEST_CODE = 10;
...
/**
 * Fires an intent to spin up the "file chooser" UI and select an image.
 */
public void performFileSearch() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType(uri, "text/*");

    startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

> After the user selects a document in the picker, onActivityResult()
>   gets called. The resultData parameter contains the URI that points to
>   the selected document. Extract the URI using getData(). When you have
>   it, you can use it to retrieve the document the user wants.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent resultData) {

    if (requestCode == READ_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        Uri uri = null;
        if (resultData != null) {
            uri = resultData.getData();
            Log.i(TAG, "Uri: " + uri.toString());
            showImage(uri);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to open particular folder.

Comment: This response doesn't answer the question at all. OP is looking to find how to open folders, not files or documents (you're answering for documents/files).

Comment: Instead OP should use Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE) in order to get folder picker