# Why Notification group not working in android? what I am doing wrong?

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications

**Here I have attached my notification utils class where I am trying to group my notification but every time I am getting separate notification, I have passed notification id which is unique for all the notification. It is used when I want to remove specific notification from the panel.**

```
public class NotificationUtils {

private static final String TAG = "NotificationUtilss";

private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "channel";
private static final String CHANNEL_NAME = "my_channel";
private static final String GROUP_KEY_PN = "com.demo.app.PN";
private static final String URL = "url";
private static final String ACTIVITY = "activity";
Map<String, Class> activityMap = new HashMap<>();
private Context mContext;

public NotificationUtils(Context mContext) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    //Populate activity map
    activityMap.put("Activity1", Activity1.class);
    activityMap.put("Activity2", Activity2.class);
    activityMap.put("Activity3", Activity3.class);
}

public void displayNotification(NotificationVO notificationVO, Intent resultIntent) {
    {
        String notification_id = notificationVO.getNotification_id();
        String message = notificationVO.getMessage();
        String title = notificationVO.getTitle();
        String iconUrl = notificationVO.getIconUrl();
        String action = notificationVO.getAction();
        String destination = notificationVO.getActionDestination();
        Bitmap iconBitMap = null;
        if (iconUrl != null) {
            iconBitMap = getBitmapFromURL(iconUrl);
        }
        final int icon = R.drawable.logo;

        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent;

        if (URL.equals(action)) {
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse(destination));
            resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, notificationIntent, 
0);
        } else if (ACTIVITY.equals(action) && activityMap.containsKey(destination)) {
            resultIntent = new Intent(mContext, activityMap.get(destination));
            resultPendingIntent =
                    PendingIntent.getActivity(
                            mContext,
                            0,
                            resultIntent,
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                    );
        } else {
            resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | 
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            resultPendingIntent =
                    PendingIntent.getActivity(
                            mContext,
                            0,
                            resultIntent,
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                    );
        }

        final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext, 
CHANNEL_ID);
        Notification notification;
        if (iconBitMap == null) {
            //When Inbox Style is applied, user can expand the notification
            NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
            inboxStyle.addLine(message);
            inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle(title);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                notification = mBuilder
                        .setTicker(title)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setContentTitle(title)
                        .setContentText(message)
                        .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                        .setStyle(inboxStyle)
                        .setWhen(new Date().getTime())
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), 
icon))
                        .setGroup(GROUP_KEY_PN)
                        .setGroupSummary(true)
                        .build();
            }
        }
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) 
mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, 
NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
        NotificationManagerCompat.from(mContext).notify(Integer.parseInt(notification_id), 
notification);
    }
}
}
```

I am in need of help applying only notification style is grouping the notification but applying group & group summary not working.

Comment: Have you tried by removing group summary?

Comment: @ShripadJadhav Yes, I have tried but it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set an unique identifier since you use `setGroupSummary` true, and also create the summary and the actual notification differently. If you want a summary, you need to:

```
val SUMMARY_ID = 0 // This is unique
notify(SUMMARY_ID, summaryNotification)
```

```
val SUMMARY_ID = 0
val GROUP_KEY_WORK_EMAIL = "com.android.example.WORK_EMAIL"

val newMessageNotification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this@MainActivity, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notify_email_status)
        .setContentTitle(emailObject1.getSummary())
        .setContentText("You will not believe...")
        .setGroup(GROUP_KEY_WORK_EMAIL)
        .build()

val summaryNotification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this@MainActivity, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setContentTitle(emailObject.getSummary())
        //set content text to support devices running API level < 24
        .setContentText("Two new messages")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notify_summary_status)
        //build summary info into InboxStyle template
        .setStyle(NotificationCompat.InboxStyle()
                .addLine("Alex Faarborg Check this out")
                .addLine("Jeff Chang Launch Party")
                .setBigContentTitle("2 new messages")
                .setSummaryText("janedoe@example.com"))
        //specify which group this notification belongs to
        .setGroup(GROUP_KEY_WORK_EMAIL)
        //set this notification as the summary for the group
        .setGroupSummary(true)
        .build()

NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).apply {
    notify(emailNotificationId, newMessageNotification)
    notify(SUMMARY_ID, summaryNotification)
}
```

Check the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/group) for more information.

Comment: adding summary_id removes previous notification

Comment: That is why I told you to check the full documentation, if you check the documentation, you will see that you have to create the notification that arrives as one object, and the summary as another object. I'll copy paste the example from the documentation here, but I didn't wanna clutter here that much, please check it out!

Comment: Thank you brother, It's work like a charm .. Also before your comment I saw document in detail. Thanks a lot for your help. From next time on-words I will make sure to read document properly.

Comment: Can you help me out for my this query? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58976433/why-it-is-not-opening-defined-folder-via-intent-in-android?noredirect=1#comment104233080_58976433

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want the summary then try by removing it or with a summary checkout the example of developer [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/group#set_a_group_summary)